# How to modify from a thread label.text in other form in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a project with 2 forms.
Form1 and form2.

For Form1, the code is:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim thread As System.Threading.Thread

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Form2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub countup(ByVal startFrom As Integer)
    For startFrom = startFrom To startFrom + 10000
        startFrom += 1
        Form2.Label1.Text = startFrom
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf countup)
    thread.Start(1000)
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    thread.Abort()
End Sub
End Class
```

In Form2 i only a label named label1.
I need to refresh the label1.text on Form2 from the thread i started in Form1.
The program runs without errors, but nothing happens. Label1.text at form2 does not modifies.
How to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: [**Performing thread-safe calls using Control.Invoke()**](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/1913/threading/6235/performing-thread-safe-calls-using-control-invoke#t=201706240759182674836) - though in this case you should call `Me.Invoke()` and _**not**_ `Form2.Label1.Invoke()`. This is because when you access the default instance of a form a new instance created on the thread you're currently in (in this case your background thread, instead of the actual UI thread).

Comment: Sorry, but i do not understand. Label1 is not on Form1, is on Form2...

Comment: Doesn't matter where it is or what control you invoke as long as it's in the UI thread. Just check my link and instead of `LogTextBox.Invoke` you write `Me.Invoke` (same goes for `LogTextBox.InvokeRequired`). The rest of the information is in the link, but if you have any questions feel free to ask me.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. I just wanted to make sure that you don't write `Form2.Label1.Invoke()` because that won't work. The best practice is to always use `Me.Invoke()` if you are doing it from within a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```
Invoke(Sub()
          Form2.Label1.Text = startFrom
       End Sub)
```

Comment: Nice! But you ought to check `InvokeRequired` as well. If it returns `False` then it is unnecessary to invoke because it adds extra overhead.

Comment: invokeRequired is false, no error, but does not work if i do not call  invoke :-s

Comment: `InvokeRequired` will return `False` before the form is shown and its handle has been created. -- Remember to check `Me.InvokeRequired` (or just `InvokeRequired`) _**and NOT**_ `Form2.Label1.InvokeRequired` (for the same reasons you shouldn't call `Form2.Label1.Invoke()`).

Comment: Yes, that is odd... If the current form is visible and you are in another thread `InvokeRequired` should return `True`. Just wanna make sure: you aren't setting `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` anywhere, right? Because if you are, **you shouldn't do that**.

Comment: Yes i'm doing it... can you explain, please, why i shouldntp't do this? Thanks

Comment: `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` is only there for _**debugging purposes**_ if you know how to use it. When it's `True` (default) the .NET runtime will check for illegal cross-thread calls and if one occurs, throw an exception. -- An example of an illegal cross-thread call is when you try to modify `Label1.Text` from a background thread _**without calling**_ `Invoke()`.

Comment: Setting `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `False` will remove this built-in check which will quite certainly cause concurrency issues, desynchronize the flow of your app, and cause other unexpected behaviour which may or may not break your app.

Comment: Simply put: _**NEVER, EVER**_ change `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` unless _**you know exactly**_ what you are doing. Otherwise it should always be set to `True` (which it is by default).